# Qasr prayer when camping?

Tags: salat, shiism, salat-al-qasr

I am leaving for a 2 night, 3 day camp tomorrow and wanted to know whether I should offer Qasr namaz (prayer) or complete namaz. the base camp is around 52 km from my home, and we have to trek for around 2-3 hours to reach the camp site.

Comment: Is this a camp for army cadets? Iv been through the same lmao

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, based on the distance of that (as you mentioned 52km...),so, it seems that you should prayer in Qasar form. Secondly you should note that there are other conditions for Qasar prayer too, for instance:

Based on Islamic Jurisprudence, a Traveller (whose prayer must be shortened, not complete) is:

> A person whose travel exceeds the Shar'i distance, that is, the
>   covered distance (whether going or going and returning combined) must
>   be at least eight Shar'i leagues (approximately 45 km.)
>
> From the beginning of the trip, the traveller must be aware of
>   covering or exceeding the mentioned distance; and must remain so until
>   reaching the distance.
>
> The traveller must not cross his hometown anywhere within the
>   mentioned distance; neither should he remain somewhere ten days or
>   more.
>
> The traveller must not travel for Haram purposes.
>
> The traveller must not be of nomads who mostly travel.
>
> Travelling must not be his job.
>
> The traveller must cross the Tarakhkhus Limit.

For further information and source, refer to: [en.wikishia.net](http://en.wikishia.net/view/Qasr_Prayer)

Comment: Thanks for the info. I had the confusion of of long 1 Shar'i league is. I thought one is equal to 28km, that is why I asked this question here 

Comment: Your welcome, hopefully the answer + complete detailed source can be helpful for you. Good luck.

Comment: What is the tarakkhus limit?

Comment: Good question, (of course I am not certain if it is in Sunni fiqh too, but in  Shia: http://en.wikishia.net/view/Limit_of_Tarakhkhus )

Comment: Thanks, of course there's something similar too, but AFAIK the opinions might be different and the term limit of tarakhkhus حَدُّ التَرَخُّص was unknown to me. Most sunnis seem to consider somewhere around 81 km as this limit!